# Ajax extraction array

Tags: javascript, ajax

I write here my little question about ajax and javascript function...
I work on little application who take some data with my server ...all work well ...my question is this...i save the data from ajax on array create out side the function ,if i call it inside the function work well but if i call out side the array is empty...
This is the code ...

```
function ProcDatJSON() {
    if (Xrt.readyState == 4) {
        var data = JSON.parse(Xrt.responseText); 
        for(i=0; i < data.link.length; i++)
        {   
            vect.push(data.link[i].title);
            vect.push(data.link[i].uri);
            blockRight.push(vect);   
        }
        document.getElementById("tab1").appendChild(document.createTextNode(blockRight[0]));
    }
}
```

So i put

```
Xrt.onreadystatuschange=ProDatJSON;
```

And print on broswe the value...but if i call the array as

```
document.writeln(blockRight[0])
```

Not give me the value but undefinited.

Comment: Where is `array` defined, and where do you think do you assign the value to it?

Comment: `eval(vect)`? what's that???

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all of your actual code

Comment: Sorry eval(vect)  not right...add value on array as blockRight.push(vect).   The vect and blckRight arw definited out side the function and if i call inside it give me the value ,but not outside

Comment: A normal behavior, because you are trying to execute `synchronous` procedure with `asynchronous` ajax call, try to use jquery deferred/promise to handle the asynchronous call

Comment: And without use jquery...

Comment: It s impossible without use jquery...i like not use more library ...thanks all